# Datepicker and calendar plugin for Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, calendar, datepicker

what could be good and suitable calendar and datepicker plugins/scripts to use with cakephp,

so that you can pick a date and write a bokking to the calendar, then later see the calendar bokkings and search bookings by dates

Answer (score 0):

Toomas I have done exactly this using FullCalendar which is a Jquery Plugin ( with Ajax )

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

It worked great for me

Comment: does this plugin allow editing the calendar only by one user - admin , or it allows each user to have their own individual calendar for managing their events

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Been Skiing.

Regarding user and admin it is easily implemented. In my system users login and add their events and the admin logs in and sees all created events. Its just a matter of passing a user id and storing the events in a simple table